# using lambda to verify all elements in list

Tags: python, lambda

i have a list of foods called "my_foods".

i would like to use a lambda function to verify that all elements from the list "good_foods" appear in the list "my_foods", and also verify that none of the elements from the list "bad_foods" appear in "my_foods".

i can solve this with nested for loops and if statements but am curious if lambdas are more elegant.

if "my_foods" has both "apple" and "carrot" the below executes successfully:

```
good_foods = ['apple', 'carrot']
junk_foods = ['soda', 'burger']

my_foods = ['banana', 'carrot', 'bread', 'apple']

result = ( filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, good_foods) and
    not filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, junk_foods) )

print result
# True
```

however, if "my_foods" has only "apple" or only "carrot", then the below still returns True, and i don't want that. i want it to return False. i want to verify that all "good_foods" are in the list "my_foods":

```
good_foods = ['apple', 'carrot']
junk_foods = ['soda', 'burger']

my_foods = ['banana', 'carrot', 'bread']

result = ( filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, good_foods) and
    not filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, junk_foods) )

print result
# True
```

additionally, if "my_foods" has neither "apple" nor "carrot", then the below returns an empty list. i want it to return False instead:

```
good_foods = ['apple', 'carrot']
junk_foods = ['soda', 'burger']

my_foods = ['banana', 'bread']

result = ( filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, good_foods) and
    not filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, junk_foods) )

print result
# []
```

lastly, if any of the "bad_foods" is in the list "my_foods" the below executes successfully and returns False, which is what i want in this instance:

```
good_foods = ['apple', 'carrot']
junk_foods = ['soda', 'burger']

my_foods = ['banana', 'carrot', 'bread', 'apple', 'soda']

result = ( filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, good_foods) and
    not filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, junk_foods) )

print result
# False
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Use list comprehensions instead of filter so you won't need lambda and your code will be readable...

Comment: `and` and `or` do not give you boolean values. `and` will give you the second true-like value or the first false-like value. `or` will give you the first true-like value or the second false-like value. If you want either `True` or `False` instead, you'd need to pass the result of the expression to `bool()`.

Comment: Well I think since your code doesn't do what you want and you're having trouble debugging it, you can hardly say the lambdas are elegant

Comment: The expression `filter(lambda x: x in my_foods, good_foods)` builds a list of all strings in `good_foods` that are in `my_foods`.  Since you want to verify that *all* good foods are in `my_foods`, this is not sufficient.  This is why several answers use `all()` and why my `filter()` solution checked the length of the resulting list.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this problem using `any()` and `all()` like so:

```
result = (all(f in my_foods for f in good_foods) and
    not any(f in my_foods for f in junk_foods))
```

If you really want to use `lambda` for this, you can do it:

```
lambda my f: f in my_foods
lambda bad f: f in junk_foods

result = all(my(f) for f in good_foods) and not any(bad(f) for f in my_foods)
```

But I would do the above with real functions:

```
def my(f):
    return f in my_foods

def bad(f):
    return f in junk_foods

result = all(my(f) for f in good_foods) and not any(bad(f) for f in my_foods)
```

Now, if you really wanted to do this with `lambda` using `map()` or `reduce()`, here is my suggestion:

```
result = (reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, map(lambda f: f in my_foods, good_foods))
    and reduce(lambda x, y: x and y, map(lambda f: f not in junk_foods, my_foods)))
```

I think the above is slightly improved if we take advantage of the built-in `bool.__and__()` function, which implements logical and on Booleans, like so:

```
result = (reduce(bool.__and__, map(lambda f: f in my_foods, good_foods))
    and reduce(bool.__and__, map(lambda f: f not in junk_foods, my_foods)))
```

But here's a solution using `filter()` if you prefer that.  `filter()` strips out elements that fail a test, so the easiest way to find out if every element passes the test is to see if the resulting list is the same length as the original list.

```
result = (len(filter(lambda f: f in my_foods, good_foods)) == len(good_foods) and
    len(filter(lambda f: f not in junk_foods, my_foods)) == len(my_foods))
```

Note that `any()` and `all()` both have "short-circuit" evaluation; they will be faster than `reduce()` in cases where not every element in the list really needs to be examined.  For example, if the first item in the list is in the `junk_foods` list, the `any()` test will immediately complete and the `not any(...)` will evaluate to `False`.  The `reduce()` answer would still go through the whole `junk_foods` list.

Also note that for large lists, you will gain a big speed improvement by using sets.  Some of the other answers suggest converting the lists to sets and using set features; this is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
good_foods = ['apple', 'carrot']
junk_foods = ['soda', 'burger']

my_foods = ['banana', 'carrot', 'bread', 'apple', 'soda']

result = all( map( lambda x: x in my_foods, good_foods ) ) and 
         not( any( map( lambda x: x in junk_foods, my_foods ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you just can't use:

```
bool(set(my_foods).difference(junk_foods).intersection(good_foods))
```

So:

- remove all junk foods from `my_foods`
- make sure non-junk items are `good_foods`
- convert result to boolean, so [] is False, anything left with good is True

Will be quick, and is easy to read.

The common case appears to be non-junk foods... So let's do:

```
non_junk = set(my_foods).difference(junk_foods)
```

All good foods are in non_junk foods:

```
set(good_foods).issubset(non_junk)
```

Good foods that aren't junk

```
non_junk.intersection(good_foods)
```

Comment: if both `good_foods` and `junk_foods` were defined as sets: `set(my_foods) - junk_foods & good_foods`

Comment: @JBernardo Actually, this may not yield the correct answer (it yields the logical answers, but...)... I'm just re-reading the OP...

Comment: using `any` or `all` can be faster since it can short circuit. `difference` and `intersection` need to process the entire lists

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing your description, gives

```
all(food in my_foods for food in good_foods) and \
not any(food in my_foods for food in junk_foods)
```

It will be more efficient if you make my_foods a set

```
>>> good_foods = ['apple', 'carrot']
>>> junk_foods = ['soda', 'burger']
>>> my_foods = {'banana', 'carrot', 'bread', 'apple'}
>>> all(food in my_foods for food in good_foods) and \
... not any(food in my_foods for food in junk_foods)
True
>>> my_foods = {'banana', 'carrot', 'bread'}
>>> all(food in my_foods for food in good_foods) and \
... not any(food in my_foods for food in junk_foods)
False
>>> my_foods = {'banana', 'bread'}
>>> all(food in my_foods for food in good_foods) and \
... not any(food in my_foods for food in junk_foods)
False
>>> my_foods = {'banana', 'carrot', 'bread', 'apple', 'soda'}
>>> all(food in my_foods for food in good_foods) and \
... not any(food in my_foods for food in junk_foods)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert all your lists to sets and do:

```
result = my_foods >= good_foods and not my_foods & junk_foods
```

So your foods must contain all the good ones and none of the junk ones

To avoid processing the whole `junk_food` set, you can do:

```
result = my_foods >= good_foods and my_foods.isdisjoint(junk_foods)
```